# Necessary condition for convergence of improper integral.

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

If $\int_0^{\infty} f(s)ds$  is convergent , then we can't say this $\lim_{s\rightarrow \infty} f(s) = 0$ if $\lim_{s\rightarrow \infty} f(s)$ doesn't exist,
But here if f is nonnegative , then is it also true?
I can't find here such counter example when f is nonnegative, please help me!

Comment: No, why not take $|f(x)|$ of whatever your previous counterexample is?

Comment: But always a convergence improper integral doesn't imply absolutely convergence?

Comment: Yes, but there's a good chance your specific counterexample works with absolute values, what was it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x)=n^{3}(\frac 1 {n^{3}}-|x-n|)$ for  $n-\frac 1{n^{3}} < x < n+\frac 1{n^{3}}$ for $n=2,3,...$ and $0$ outside these intervals. Then $f(n)=1$ for all $n$  but $f$ is integrable.

Comment: I could have used interval of length $\frac 1 {n^{2}}$ around $n$  and defined $f$ suitably, but that is not a  significant improvement.